# How do I get linux server to use local PHP.ini in a shared environment?

Tags: fastcgi, local, shared-hosting, php

I'm on shared server environment (Dreamhost.com uses Linux/Debian).

I followed their instructions @ http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Advanced_PHP_configuration
on setting up a local PHP5 instance on my user account so that I could use APC (php5 accelerator)

A couple of caveats is that I dont have php5 installed on the root directory "/home/php5" as assumed by the instructions/install script

rather I have it in another directory "home/subdir-path/php5", so I had to change the script to address that.

I tried adding this dir to the env $PATH

but when I do phpinfo(), i see that it's not using the local php.ini settings =[

Any thoughts on how to remedy this is greatly appreciated.

==OR==

If someone could show me the right steps to setup a custom php5 instance, with fastcgi, and APC (php cache/accelerator) that'd be just as great.

Comment: Your question should be posted at Serverfault.

Comment: ok thanks. 

http://serverfault.com/questions/69150/how-do-i-get-linux-server-to-use-local-php-ini-in-a-shared-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

symlink from the expected location to the location where php.ini really is

Comment: thats not the solution i was looking for really. shouldnt there be a way to resolve this in some config file somewhere or in .bashrc?